# Hide auto pop up for google login api javascript

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I used new Google login using new [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user) , I have problem that the when the page reloaded popup shown for login by google for login google accounts, I tried to find a way from the documentation but no result.

Is there a way to prevent the popup from shown?

[image]

Comment: This is a personal popup which each Google user decides to turn on or off in security settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely ! I had the same issue a while back.
Here you can see the structure of the Javascript API. Remove the     `google.accounts.id.prompt();` line. Below is the complete initialization code for this.

```
window.onload = function () {
google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
  callback: handleCredentialResponse
});
// remove this line
google.accounts.id.prompt();
};
```

For the sign in or sign up with google btn only the `accounts.id.initialize` is required.

Take a look at this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference) for further customization